# Mocha TypeScript Error "this.timeout is not a function" without Arrow Function

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I try to create a test with mocha that has a timeout. However, I got an error `TypeError: this.timeout is not a function`.

This seems to be an easy to solve error. But when I searched for this error I always find the solution: `Don't use arrow functions`. Unfortunatly that does not seem to be the Problem here.

---

My simplified Test:

```
import 'mocha';
import 'ts-mockito';

describe('Function', function () {

    it('function', function (done: MochaDone) {
        this.timeout(5);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used another approach using anotaitions

```
@suite(timeout(3000), slow(1000))
export class MainTest {

    @test async Test1() {
        ...
    }
}
```

As discribed in the repo [mocha-ts](https://github.com/pana-cc/mocha-typescript).